# how to print text of frames with htmlunit

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

Consider the following html file a.html

```
<html>
    <frameset>
       <frame src="frame_a.html">
    </frameset>
</html>
```

The frame_a.html is the following

```
<html>
    <body>
       aaaaaa
    </body>
</html>
```

The following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.util.List;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.FrameWindow;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class TestFramset {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FailingHttpStatusCodeException, MalformedURLException, IOException, InterruptedException {
WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(true);
client.getOptions().setCssEnabled(true);
client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("file:///...a.html");
System.out.println("page as text will give nothing:"+page.asText());
System.out.println("recursive function will give:"+getText(page));
}

public static String getText (HtmlPage page) {
    String text = page.asText();
    List<FrameWindow> frames = page.getFrames();
    for (FrameWindow frame:frames) {
        text += getText((HtmlPage) frame.getEnclosedPage());
    }
    return text;
}
```

}

will give the output

page as text will give nothing:

recursive function will give:aaaaaa

My question is if the fact that page.asText function does not return the text of the frames is desired and if my way to get the text of the frames recursively is the best way

Comment: Code and output are both OK. What is the question? Regarding the "best way" that only depends on your requirements. If you've been asked to recursively extract the texts of all frames and concatenate them in a string, then you're doing it right.

Comment: I had two questions. If page.asText behaves well that it does not return the text of the frames and if the recursive approach is the best way to get the text of all frames, or if there exists a helper function which makes this for me.

Comment: ´.asText()´ will return only the visible text of the page. It is not clear if that is what you expect (you haven't specified your expected result your question and I understand "aaaaaaa" is the expected result). Regarding the recursive funcion, if the result you are getting is what you expect, then it is the way to go, however, I can't imagine why would someone concatenate so much text from different pages in an awfully long string. I mean, the issue, is not how to do it but why are you doing it.